# String Validation with help of Regex - PHP

Tags: php, regex

I want a regex that can validate RegX to ensure no white space/escape characters can be used, especially `CR` and `LF`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: so what exactly have you tried?

Comment: If you don't want to include any whitespace or escape characters, just reject the input if it matches `\\|\s`

Comment: `code' $q = "Firstname Lastname";
$regex = "@(https?://([-\w\.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.#-]*(\?\S+)?[^\.\s])?).*$)@";
$text = preg_replace($regex, ' ', $q);`code'

currently I have used this regex to remove any URL from the string but my fortify security application scanner is telling me to remove white space and escape charters from. if possible give me regex which I can use

Comment: @emsimpson92 can you please help to with regex. It will be a great help if you provide me the full regex.

Comment: `if(preg_match("/\\|\s/gm", $teststring))` ---> input is invalid

Answer (score 0):

If you use something like below, it will strip white spaces from a string.

```
$stripped_string = preg_replace("/[\s]/", "", $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex is not needed here. Just use method `strpos()`, [here's reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

And use it to see, if there are any invalid characters rpesent:

```
$needles = array("\n", "\r", "\t", " ", ...);
foreach($needles as $needle) {
    $res = strpos($haystack, $needle, $offset);
    if ($res !== false) ...do something
}
```